# Can't precisely understand what and how to use the GridBagConstraints. As-Is vs. Should-Be

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am messing around with the GridBagLayout. I have understood it somewhat, hence was able to make this layout. but my As-Is is not matching with my should be. here are the screens.

As-Is :(
[image: As-Is :(]

[image: Should Be :s]
Should Be :s

I understand that i have to tweak it a bit so that the size is set (`setSize()`). But the real tricky one is getting the "Add Contact" `JLabel`  to be in the center at the top.
Waiting for your replies. Thanks in Advance.

Here's My Code

```
package SimpleCRUD;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ContactListFrame extends JFrame{
    JButton Button1, Button2;
    JTextField textField1, textField2, textField3;
    JLabel label1, label2, label3 , label4;
    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints Constraint = new GridBagConstraints();

    public ContactListFrame() {
        super("All Contacts");
        Button1 = new JButton("Add");
        Button2 = new JButton("Cancel");
        textField1 = new JTextField(15);
        textField2 = new JTextField(15);
        textField3 = new JTextField(15);
        label4 = new JLabel("Add Contact");
        label4.setFont (new Font("fallan", 1, 25));
        label1 = new JLabel("First Name:");
        label2 = new JLabel("Last Name:");
        label3 = new JLabel("Phone Number:");

        setLayout(layout);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 200);
        setResizable(false);
        Constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        Constraint.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        addComponent(label4, 0, 1, 1, 1);
        addComponent(textField1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        addComponent(textField2, 2, 1, 1, 1);
        addComponent(textField3, 3, 1, 1, 1);
        addComponent(label1, 1, 0, 1, 1);
        addComponent(label2, 2, 0, 1, 1);
        addComponent(label3, 3, 0, 1, 1);
        addComponent(Button1, 4, 0, 2, 1);
        addComponent(Button2, 4, 1, 2, 1);
    }

    public void addComponent (Component comp, int row, int col, int width, int height){
        Constraint.gridx = col;
        Constraint.gridy = row;
        Constraint.gridwidth = width;
        Constraint.gridheight = height;
        layout.setConstraints(comp, Constraint);
        add(comp);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could we see the code that is generating the layout?

Comment: Did you construct the 'Add Contact' JLabel with SwingConstants.CENTER as a second parameter? And have you played around with gridwidth?

Comment: You might also want to check out GroupLayout introduced with Java 6 - it can do most of the things GrindBagLayout does and is IMO much easier to use.

Comment: I have added the code. @thasc how should i add the `SwingConstants`

Comment: One instructive approach is to specify `GridBagLayout` in the NetBeans GUI editor, adjust _ad lib_, and look at the generated code.

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard.  Have three panels, one for the title, one for the labels and text fields, and one for the buttons.  Add those three panels to the frame using gridbaglayout.  Then again using gridbaglayout, add the title label to the title panel, the textfields and labels to the middle panel, and then finally the buttons to the button panel.  Gridbaglayout tends to be quite verbose, but I personally only ever use the gbl.  Even for super simple layouts, it just always looks the most professional to me.  I will write an example if I get time today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation of GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html), there's a fairly good example of GridBagConstraints usage.

Here's your code modified to use GridBagConstraints

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class ContactListFrame extends JFrame{
    JButton Button1, Button2;
    JTextField textField1, textField2, textField3;
    JLabel label1, label2, label3 , label4;
    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints Constraint = new GridBagConstraints();

    public ContactListFrame() {
        super("All Contacts");
        Button1 = new JButton("Add");
        Button2 = new JButton("Cancel");
        textField1 = new JTextField(15);
        textField2 = new JTextField(15);
        textField3 = new JTextField(15);
        label4 = new JLabel("Add Contact");
        label4.setFont (new Font("fallan", 1, 25));
        label1 = new JLabel("First Name:");
        label2 = new JLabel("Last Name:");
        label3 = new JLabel("Phone Number:");

        setLayout(layout);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 200);
        setResizable(false);
        Constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        Insets ins = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Constraint.insets = ins;//this does the padding
        Constraint.weightx = 0.0;
        Constraint.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;//end row
        add(label4, Constraint);
        Constraint.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;//next to last component
        add(label1, Constraint);
        Constraint.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;//end row
        add(textField1, Constraint);
        Constraint.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;//next to last component
        add(label2, Constraint);
        Constraint.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;//end row
        add(textField2, Constraint);
        Constraint.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;//next to last component
        add(label3, Constraint);
        Constraint.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;//end row
        add(textField3, Constraint);
        Constraint.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;//next to last component
        add(Button1, Constraint);
        Constraint.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;//end row
        add(Button2, Constraint);
    }        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
      new ContactListFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The output looks like this

[image]

Comment: Why do you keep resetting `weightx`?